# whats the best route to add graphic assets to a google web app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Am trying to build a website usine google app script (to be later embeded in a Google Sites site) - unlike normal hosting there is no file storage area to store assets such as graphics... whats the best route to include these with the script?

ideally I would like to keep everything within google integrated services so no third party hosting if possible...

for example I need to add image url to background-image css property - using normal cpanel hosting I would have it is assets folder alongside all html files... google drive or photos wont let me creat a normal url link so...

Comment: Google drive does have a alternative  normal link.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "google drive or photos wont let me create a normal url link"?

Comment: I have added images to background URL by converting them to DataURLs

Comment: thanks all - I have worked it out now using the id frol the shared link after "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" - it seems to work but being a work around I know I may find google changing the api down the line which could break this...